# ngx-bootstrap data from http service

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to write a typeahead using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead). In order to get the values for the list, it requires an http.get from the API. So I added an event binding to my input to trigger the http request and update the components array for the typeahead.

```
<input class="form-control"
    container="body"
    formControlName="prefix"
    typeaheadOptionField="name"
    [typeahead]="accounts"
    (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelect($event)"
    (keyup)="getAccounts()">
```

then in my component, the getAccounts() method is fired on keyup:

```
getAccounts() {
    this.users.accountTypeAhead(this.userForm.value.prefix).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.accounts = this.apiHandler.responseHandler(response);
            console.log(this.accounts);
        },
        (err) => {
            this.apiHandler.errorHandler(err);
        }
    );
}
```

this calls the service to make the get request:

```
accountTypeAhead(param, url = this.accountAutoComplete) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('prefix', param);
    return this.http.get(url, {params: params});
}
```

this all seems to be partially working. The keyup event is fired and when I watch in console, I can see the that `this.accounts` is update with the results.

The challenge that I am having is that the typeahead dropdown is not showing as/after I type. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you declare accounts on the component without initializing, just like:

```
MyComponent {
    accounts;
    // other code here
    // and getAccounts() method
}
```

Now, I guess `typeahead` is confused that first time and assumes your accounts isn't an observable. So when you change the reference to it later, the typeahead instance doesn't get this new reference to your array. Try like the example in the docs, with declaring it as observable right away:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    // Runs on every search
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
  }).mergeMap((token: string) => this.filterResults(token));
}

// fired every time search string is changed
filterResults(token: string) {
  // adjust the remote url.
  const url = `${this.url}?searchTerm=token`;
  return this.http.get(url)
    // if your backend does the filtering, just return the results.
    // oterwise we have to massage them a bit
    .map((results: any[]) => results.filter(res => res.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(token.toLowerCase()) > -1));
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxg-bootstrap-typeahead-async?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is a full working example of it.

Comment: I think I am getting closer to this, I am now getting `results.filter is not a function`

Comment: That is good, probably just means that your results item is not an array, or not even a proper json. What do you see in network tab from this endpoint?